Parameterize a Snowflake TASK
I have 10 stored procedures created in snowflake. For these, we had to create 10 Task to schedule. Is there anyway, we can create only 1 Task and parameterise the call of stored procedures inside that Task. So that we have only 1 Task created and this can be used to call all the stored procedures by passing them as parameter. Any help/suggestions pls? Thanks in Advance.
I have not tried any and no idea on how to proceed with this.

From where in azure, are you trying to execute the stored procedures? from ADF?

Azure as of now, we are using only ADLS for source file storage. Our idea is o fully implement all in Snowflake alone. So the Store Proc is executed through Snowflake TASK.

Please add any approach you tried and facing blockers.

@JayashankarGS - No, I have not tried any approach. I just know that, it is not possible to write more than one command while executing TASK. So, I was not sure how to frame one.

you could use dynamic sql in the task to triger the procedures
DECLARE
    procedure_list ARRAY := ARRAY['proc1', 'proc2', ..., 'proc10'];
    i INT := 1;
BEGIN
    WHILE i <= ARRAY_SIZE(procedure_list) DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL ' || procedure_list[i] || '();';
        i := i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;


Thanks a lot for this method. But, my need will not fit into this. TASK-A is calling a Store Proc-1. After TASK-A is success, TASK-B & TASK-C will be triggered. My Need is, instead of creating this TASK-B & TASK-C separately, I should use TASK-A only, but calling the Store Proc name I want to parameterize. I believe I am making my point clear. In this way, I will have only 1 TASK and inside this TASK the Store Porc will be changed as per my need and this same TASK can also be called as child task also.
